# If a users user group has the same name as a usergroup in the usergroup database, then display color

Tags: php, html, mysql

So basically I have a user group system on my site, where you can assign certain groups to different users. Right now, it's half working. The issue is that only one user group at a time is being used.

[As you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWPqw.png)

I want every user with a user group to have their user groups color shown, but right now it's not doing that.

Here is my code:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`, `name`,`color1`,`color2` FROM `usergroup`")) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $userfromdb =  $row["name"];
                $color1 = $row["color1"];
                $color2 = $row["color2"];
            }
        }
```

Later down the line, I have the code that makes a user with a user group its color

```
<span style="background: #ffffff;background: url('/assets/img/textparticle.gif'), linear-gradient(to right, <?php if ($usergroup === $userfromdb) { echo $color1; } ?> 0%, <?php if ($usergroup === $userfromdb) { echo $color2; } ?> 100%);-webkit-background-clip: text;-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;font-weight:700;<?php if ($usergroup === $userfromdb) { echo "text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #32a852"; } ?>">
```

[Here is what the usergroup database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8CBS.png)

[Here is what the account database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMiha.png)

Comment: Your query selects all the user groups, then loops through the result overwriting the colours until they've all been read. You'll always get the colours of the last user group in the query.

Comment: You're overwriting the colour values every time you loop. Then you try to use the values after the loop ends, so you'll only see the last one.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular How do I make it so it matches the users user group to a user group in the database, then takes the user group and gets its colors then displays them in the span?

Comment: Build `<span` in `while` or output the HTML in the `while`.

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause to your query selecting only the usergroup that matches the one you're working with.

Comment: Why in the usergroup database, in the usergroup table,usergroup column name FAGGOT the colors are just black and white?  BTW, you need a WHERE clause in you query.  Like WHERE `name` LIKE 'FAGGOT'

Comment: @Misunderstood lmaoooo, it was a placeholder. but I got the issue fixed hahah

Comment: I feel like if you would just query that user if it belong to certain group and not storing the hex color too on database would be alot easier,  lesser point of failure or accidentally leaving a attack vector for SQL injections but hey that's just my opinion

Comment: DId the answer work

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this.  Use the **usergroup** variable to select only one row.  It is also faster than fetching all users and iterating through them.

```php
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`, `name`,`color1`,`color2` FROM `usergroup` where `name`='$usergroup`")) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $userfromdb =  $row["name"];
                $color1 = $row["color1"];
                $color2 = $row["color2"];
            }
        }
```